# How can I load GLTF or GLB files via Webpack 5?

Tags: webpack, three.js

I have been trying to work with three.js and webpack. Even though I managed to load glb and gltf files along with their texture files like jpeg,png, I got the error below:

```
error SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFLoader.parse (GLTFLoader.js:245:21)
    at Object.eval [as onLoad] (GLTFLoader.js:135:11)
    at eval (three.module.js:39784:38)
```

I tried to use other gltf files but I got same error all the time. How can I load glb or gltf files along with their texture files with webpack?

Here is my webpack config and index.js files look like:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/template.html"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(glb|gltf|bin)$/i,
                type: 'asset',
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images/source'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset',
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images/textures'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```js
const path = require('path')
const common = require('./webpack.config')
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]',
        clean: true
    }
})
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```js
const path = require('path')
const common = require('./webpack.config')
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
})
```

**index.js**
(I had to imported images, because I couldn't find other way to load them with webpack. Please let me know if there is another way without `import` or `require`)

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
import model3d from './assets/source/OilCan.glb'
import base3d from './assets/textures/OilCan_baseColor_2.png'
import metallic3d from './assets/textures/OilCan_occlusionRoughnessMetallic_1@channels=B.png'
import mettalic3d2 from "./assets/textures/OilCan_occlusionRoughnessMetallic_1@channels=G.png"
import mettalic3d3 from "./assets/textures/OilCan_occlusionRoughnessMetallic_1@channels=R.png"
import normal3d from './assets/textures/OilCan_normal_0.png'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()

const light = new THREE.SpotLight({color: 0xba0f7b, intensity: 0.5})
light.position.x = 13

scene.add(light)
const loader = new GLTFLoader()
loader.load(model3d, function(glb) {
    scene.add(glb.scene);
    console.log('glb',glb)
}, undefined, function(error){
    console.log('error', error)
})

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    myCube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    myCube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate()
```